# How to return json object with QHttpServer

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside6

I am trying to create a simple rest api with QHttpServer in Python. I had checked examples in C++. However, I couldn't get it to work in Python. When `callback_api` returns a string, it is visible as plain text, but any other return value creates a response with empty body and status code 200. Moreover status codes other than 200 do not have any effect. What is the correct way to return json and/or desired status code?

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtHttpServer import QHttpServer,QHttpServerRequest, QHttpServerResponse, QHttpServerResponder
from PySide6.QtNetwork import QHostAddress
from PySide6.QtCore import QJsonArray, QJsonValue


def test(req: QHttpServerRequest):
    d = {"key": "value"}
    return QHttpServerResponse(d)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
server = QHttpServer()
server.listen(QHostAddress("127.0.0.1"), 5005)
server.route("/api", test)
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. Currently PySide does not support a view handler which returns a `QHttpServerResponse`. (See [the source](https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/sources/pyside6/PySide6/glue/qhttpserver.cpp?h=6.6.1#n14) for a detail.)

Either use Qt HTTP Server library in C++ or use other Python web frameworks such as Flask, FastAPI, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be nice, if this behavior was explained in PySide documentation